# Update parent form while a child form is also updating

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I have a main form with subscription to an event aggregator, on each event received, the main form update the UI.

And I have a child form that requires update their controls, but it looks like while the main form is updating their UI (when new events arrives), the child form is blocked until the main form finish the update process.

Is there a way to update both forms asynchronously?

The main form subscription code:

```
MessageHub.Instance.Subscribe<Notification>(async (ev) => await UpdateMainUI(ev));
```

And the child form is called after a button is pressed:

```
if (infoWnd == null || infownd.IsDisposed)
{
    infoWnd = new InfoForm();
}
infoWnd.Show(this);
```

Comment: This looks like a "can't see the forest for the trees" problem.  We can't see the trees either.  There is just no practical way that anything named "UpdateMainUI" is ever going to run asynchronously.  Probably the first thing that method does is undo the damage that async did by using Begin/Invoke().  Keep UI user-friendly, don't dump thousands of rows in a grid control, and neither you nor your user are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Then, it is not a good idea to update using async method? I'm using the Synchronization.Current.

Comment: Well, it is certainly not a good idea if you can't figure out how your code works anymore.  Using Synchronization.Current is just another way to stop code from running asynchronously, its Post/Send method calls Begin/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks!, I'm refactoring my forms for a better UI.